# How to rename/rearrange file names in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, powershell, rename, filenames, windows-11

I had multiple photos saved in my computer with file names in `First name_Middle Name_Last Name` format. I would like to change it to `Last Name, First Name, Middle Name`.

For example:

From: `One_Two_Three`

To:   `Three, One, Two`

I did a little research but I only found a replace-like method, but not rearranging the words.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-replace` regex operator:

```
PS ~> 'One_Two_Three' -replace '([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)', '$3, $1, $2'
Three, One, Two
```

The pattern `([^_]+)` will capture any sequence of non-`_`, and we can then "rearrange" each capture in the substitution pattern `$3, $1, $2` (`$1` refers to the group that captures `One` before the first `_`, etc.).

For renaming files, you'll want to reference the `BaseName` property on each file object:

```
Get-ChildItem path\to\folder\with\pictures -File -Filter *_*_*.* |Rename-Item -NewName {($_.BaseName -replace '([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)', '$3, $1, $2') + $_.Extension}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
PS /tmp> Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *_*_*.* |
  Rename-Item -WhatIf -NewName {
    $w = $_.BaseName -split '_'; (($w[2], $w[0], $w[1]) -join ', ') + $_.Extension }
```

Output:

```
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /tmp/One_Two_Three.jpg Destination: /tmp/Three, One, Two.jpg".
```

Remove `-WhatIf` to do real renaming